# HTML 5 input check: the validation message appears only by repeated calling

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, dom-events

I have a form including two password fields (password, password confirmation). I need their issues about different values to look like a standard HTML-5 pop-up message (see the illustration):

[image]

For this purpose I have attached the html5/JS function `setCustomValidity()` to the password2 field. 
`Form.submin()` triggers that checking, but the problem is that if values are different the message appears only starting from attempt #2. I.e. initial event does nothing - form doesn't send data but the message doesn't appears also. If I repeat this it appears. 
I have no any appropriate ideas why. Do you?
Here is the full inner code:

```
<script>
function validateForm(){

    var pass1=document.getElementById('password1');
    var pass2=document.getElementById('password2');

    var pass1Val=pass1.value;
    var pass2Val=pass2.value;

    if(pass1Val&&pass2Val&&(pass1Val!=pass2Val)){
        pass2.setCustomValidity("The password  confirmation is different to the password value");
        return false;
    }       
}
</script>
<form id="user-form" action="#" method="post" enctype="text/plain" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
Email:      <input type="email" id="emailField" required="required"> <br>
Tel:        <input type="tel" id="phoneField" required="required"> <br>
Password:   <input type="password" id="password1" required="required"> <br>
Password2:  <input type="password" id="password2" required="required"><br> <input type="submit" value="Send!"> </form>
```

Comment: is the button of type `submit` or `button`?

Comment: submit. I fixed the code (it has been unexpectedly cropped here).

Answer (score 0):

You have to setCustomValidity before the submit not on the submit event.

```
<form id="user-form" action="#" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Email:      <input type="email" id="emailField" required="required"> <br>
Tel:        <input type="tel" id="phoneField" required="required"> <br>
Password:   <input type="password" id="password1" required="required"> <br>
Password2:  <input type="password" id="password2" required="required"><br> <input type="submit" value="Send!"> </form>
<script>
(function(){
if(!document.createElement('input').setCustomValidity){return;}
var pass1=document.getElementById('password1');
var pass2 = document.getElementById('password2');
function validateForm(){

    var pass1=document.getElementById('password1');

    var pass1Val=pass1.value;
    var pass2Val=pass2.value;

    if(pass1Val&&pass2Val&&(pass1Val!=pass2Val)){
        pass2.setCustomValidity("The password  confirmation is different to the password value");
    } else {
        pass2.setCustomValidity("");  
    }   
}

if(pass1 && pass2){
    pass1.addEventListener('change', validateForm, false);
    pass2.addEventListener('change', validateForm, false);

    validateForm();
}
})();

</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work in this way. If the passwords are diffirent, the form submits data (no canceling). You can see your example here:  http://srgg6701.github.io/examples/JS/HTML5_inputs.html
I tryed to modify it and reached that on my localhost it prevents sending the data (see above) but then the message appears starting from the attempt #2 anyway.

Comment: Updated just add:  else {
        pass2.setCustomValidity("");  
    }

Comment: No, it won't work this way. There are 2 errors in your code. First, just calling validateForm() doesn't prevent form sending.